# Where is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config coming from?

Tags: debian, configuration, openssh

I have `openssh-server` installed on a Debian Jessie host and am trying to find the original version of the `sshd_config` file. But that was apparently not installed by `openssh-server`:

```
root@apu ~$ dpkg -S /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

What am I missing? Are there config files in Debian that are not managed by `dpkg`?

Comment: Another example is `/etc/modules` on Ubuntu. It is also generated by a maintainer script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are quite a few configuration files which aren't managed by `dpkg`; they're managed by maintainer scripts instead. In this case, in Debian 9 the original file is available as `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config`; that's copied to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by [`openssh-server.postinst`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/blob/master/debian/openssh-server.postinst). In Debian 8 the original contents are stored in [`openssh-server.postinst`](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/blob/jessie/debian/openssh-server.postinst) directly.

Comment: `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config` does not exist here. Its probably `/usr/share/doc/openssh-client/examples/sshd_config` on Debian 8 instead.

Comment: In Jessie the default configuration file's contents are *in* [the maintainer script](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/debian/openssh-server.postinst?h=jessie); I'll update my answer.